# Javascript Unit Test a function that does not accept any parameters or return anything

Tags: javascript, unit-testing

I need to write a Javascript Unit test for a method which doesn't accept any parameters or return any value. All the function does is manipulate some DOM elements.

Is there a way to unit test this? Or do I need to refactor my code in some way to unit test such functions?

Comment: You can make it return `true`/`false` based on success. Or check the DOM before and after, looking for the changes.

Comment: There certainly are ways to unit test that code without modifying it. Not sure on the specifics as I've never done it but Google it and you'll get results.